# mariadb 10.6 server and client installation ubuntu 20.04 The repository __ does not have a Release file

Tags: repository, mariadb

In a computer with ubuntu 20.04, I can not install mariadb-server and client.

I execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https -y &&  
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys 'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc' &&  
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/mariadb/repo/10.6/ubuntu focal main' && sudo apt update -y && sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
```

and it stops executing and the following error appears:

```
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/mariadb/repo/10.6/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you open it in a browser & look?

Comment: if I use the navigator I get there with the following route: https://mirrors.ptisp.pt/mariadb/mariadb-10.6/repo/ubuntu/dists/focal/